# How to design a DataBase for well structured Java API Documentation?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a scenario to design a database for [Java API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), in which I have to present the information about every class and method in a given piece of code. For example, consider:

```
1. main()
2. {
3. String foo="test";
4. foo.substring(1,2);
5. }
```

Here, I have to show documentation for class **`String`** and method **`substring`** from Java docs (The classes/methods can be any valid class/method).

My Observations:

The classes may repeat in various packages, so they can't be unique. Same goes for methods.
The method name `foo()` can be :

1) The method of this class

2) Overrides the method of some parent class

3) Simply inherits the a method.

With this info, I have following tables:

1)

```
CREATE TABLE  "JAVACLASSDESCRIPTION" 
   (    "CLASSFULLNAME" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CLASSNAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "CLASSDEFINATION" CLOB, 
    "CLASSDECLARATION" CLOB, 
    "INHERITEDCLASSES" CLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT "JAVACLASSDESCRIPTION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CLASSFULLNAME") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

`INHERITEDCLASSES` is a multi-valued attribute.I know it's a really poor thing, but I have reasons.
    1) 1st check if the method is available in `JAVAMETHODDESCRIPTION` table (Either as the class method itself, or a override method ).
2) If not, it has to be a method which is inherited for some parent class. So we have to show the documentation of method of this parent class.To save multiple searching, the value `INHERITEDCLASSES` contains is as follows(for some random class):

```
java.lang.Object: clone, equals, finalize, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, toString, wait, wait, wait
```

so that it's parent class is `java.lang.Object` followed by the list of methods, so that it's easy to match the method name.

2)

```
CREATE TABLE  "JAVAMETHODDESCRIPTION" 
   (    "CLASSFULLNAME" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "METHODNAME" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "METHODDECLARATION" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "METHODDEFINATION" CLOB
   ) ;ALTER TABLE  "JAVAMETHODDESCRIPTION" ADD CONSTRAINT "JAVAMETHODDESCRIPTION_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("CLASSFULLNAME")
      REFERENCES  "JAVACLASSDESCRIPTION" ("CLASSFULLNAME") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;
```

Sample output:

[image]

I know there are lot of design issues.How can I improve my database design?

**EDIT:**

About the multi-valued entry, if decomposed to another table may result into redundant entries.For eg. `Object` class is the super class for all.

[Link for documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to tell everything because a lot of things is unspecified, but:

a few things to consider: loaded java class is identified by unique full name (x.y.z.Myclass$Inner.class) and it's classloader. if you don't care about loaded class but only the source code (javadoc) then you can probably skip classloader.

javadoc can be at method, class, package and field level (each of them can be uniquely identified by signature)

if you want to support javadoc for inherited methods then you need to model multiple inheritance (javadoc can be inherited also from interfaces) and in your application traverse that tree top on request to display the javadoc. other option is to do the traversing during saving the content to db

another thing is versioning of library and jdk. don't know if you want to support different versions.

Comment: How about creating them as objects?

Comment: i'm not sure what do you mean. what is 'them'? how do you want to store objects in relational database?

Comment: Create the nested objects in place of multivalued attributes (store as type object)

Comment: i don't know the oracle's object capabilities. but it doesn't really matters which tool you use to model it as long as you can easily fulfil above requirements

Answer (score 0):

The best method for going about something like this, is to get to the 3rd normal form. You may not stay there, but at least by "seeing it" you learn a few things along the way about your system, the relationships, and such.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Once you get to that stage, then start looking at what you have, and ask yourself how it will behave with your specific situation. ie how are you accessing it .. is it going to perform poorly, would it help to denormalize things a little to help improve query performance, etc, etc.

Comment: I know what is 3NF or BCNF.It's just I can't figure this out in this very particular case.And apart from that multivalued thingy (if i consider it to be a single string) the design is in 3NF.

Comment: What's your entity?  "JavaClass" ? (JavaClassDescription sounds like a property of JavaClass).  Start there.  Give it a PK, and start asking what each property/attirbute is. Don't combine things.  (ie name, description, declaration, inherited classes(multiple - which might indicate another table - ) .. etc.